# Custom HTTP headers UIWebview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, http-headers

I'm developing an application for iOS in Xcode 4.5 but I have a problem with a UIWebView. I want to set a header(BASE64 code) to skip a login part. When I try this, using the [NPWebView project](http://www.nomadplanet.fr/2010/09/custom-http-headers-for-every-request-made-in-uiwebviews/) the webview always fails with an error which looks like this:

**Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x6ace650 {NSErrorFailingURLKey="MY URL", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey="MY URL"}**

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from your description exactly what's going on, but -999 usually comes from the request being cancelled, in my experience.

(See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLErrorCancelled)